# Clickable colour boxes to change chat bubble colour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chat

I have a chat application where a user can submit a message and the message appears in a chat bubble with an orange background. I've created 5 coloured div boxes which I want to link to the background colour of the chat bubble. My hope is that the user can click on one of the coloured div's and their following messages would appear in a chat bubble with that background. How could I do this?

See link for illustration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnRfE.jpg

CODE:

HTML:

```
</ul>

<div>

<input type="text" id="typetextbox" />

<button type="submit" id="submit"> </button>


</div> 

<div><img src="Images/brown-block.png" id="Brown"/></div>
<div><img src="Images/blue-block.png" id="Blue" /></div>
<div><img src="Images/red-block.png" id="Red" /></div>
<div><img src="Images/green-block.png" id="Green"/></div>
<div><img src="Images/orange-block.png" id="Orange"/></div>
```

<del>JAVA</del>JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('#typetextbox').keypress(function (e){
 if(e.keyCode == 13 ) $('#submit').click();
});

$('#submit').click(function(){
  var message = $('#typetextbox').val();
  if (message.replace(/ /g, '')){
      var positions = makeNewPosition();
      var el = $('<li>'+message+'</li>');
      $('#messagebox').append(el);
```

CSS:

```
li {
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    background: #E99D41;
    position: absolute;
    background-opacity: 50%;
    font-family:  Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;

#Blue{
    position: absolute;
    top: 88%;
    left: 25%;      
}
```

#Brown, #Red, #Green, and #Orange all same as #Blue.

I hope this all makes sense, and I'm sure its a pretty simple thing, but I would really appreciate the help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just add your specific style property to make messages look as you want

```js
var currentSelectedColor = undefined;

$('.colorPicker>div').on('click',function(e){
  currentSelectedColor = $(e.currentTarget).attr('class');
  $('#typetextbox').css('background-color',currentSelectedColor);
});

$('#submit').on('click',function(){
  var msg = $.trim($('#typetextbox').val());
  if(msg=='')
  {
    return;
  }
  $('<li/>').append($("<div/>", {
    class: currentSelectedColor? currentSelectedColor: '',
    text: msg
  })).appendTo('#messagebox');
});
```

```css
li
{
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  list-style:none;
  }

#messagebox>li>div {
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    font-family:  Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block
  }

.colorPicker>div
{
  width: 10px;
  height:10px;
  display: inline-block
  }

.red
{
  background-color: red;
  }

.green
{
  background-color: green;
  }
.blue
{
  background-color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='messagebox'>

</ul>
 
  <div class='colorPicker'>
    <div class='red'></div>
    <div class='green'></div>
    <div class='blue'></div>
   </div>
<input type="text" id="typetextbox" />

<button type="button" id="submit">Submit </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0eoh6yy5/4/)

The idea is to get the color of the clicked div and the value of the textarea and display the typed text adding the css: the chosen color, with the use of Jquery.

1.Get the color of the clicked div:

```
var color = $( this ).css( "background-color" );
```

//this refer for the clicked html element in this example it is the chosen colored div

2.get the value of the typed text:

```
var thought = jQuery("textarea#message").val();
```

3.display the result:get the result HTML element by id,add the typed text as the HTML of this element, add css: backgroud-color=submited color.

```
$( "#result" ).html( "<span style='backgroud-color:" +color + ";'>" + thought + "</span>" );
```

4.put this in a click function